# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task in stage failed，Lost task in stage : ExecutorLostFailure (executor 4 lost)

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing

I build MonoSpark(based on Spark 1.3.1) with JDK 1.7 and Hadoop 2.6.2 by this command (I edited my pom.xml so that the command can work)

```
./make-distribution.sh --tgz  -Phadoop-2.6 -Dhadoop.version=2.6.2
```

Then, I get a tgz file named 'spark-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT-bin-2.6.2.tgz'. 
  I put the tgz file on my hadoop cluster which has a master and 4 slaves.
Then, I start the spark by using the command.

```
$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-all.sh
```

The spark works well as there are 4 workers and 1 master. However, when I use spark-submit to run an example:

```
./bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.JavaWordCount --master spark://master:7077 lib/spark-examples-1.3.1-*-hadoop2.6.2.jar  input/README.md
```

I get this error on my driver like below

```
......other useless logs.....
19/03/31 22:24:41 ERROR cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 2
19/03/31 22:24:46 WARN remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave3:55311] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Disassociated].
19/03/31 22:24:50 ERROR scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 3 on slave1: remote Akka client disassociated
19/03/31 22:24:54 ERROR scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
.......other useless logs......
Exception in thread "main" 19/03/31 22:24:54 ERROR cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 4
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, slave4): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 4 lost)
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1325)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1314)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1313)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1313)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:714)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:714)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:714)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1526)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1487)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

The worker node error log is below:

```
19/03/31 22:25:11 INFO worker.Worker: Asked to launch executor app-20190331222434-0000/2 for JavaWordCount
19/03/31 22:25:19 INFO worker.Worker: Executor app-20190331222434-0000/2 finished with state EXITED message Command exited with code 50 exitStatus 50
19/03/31 22:25:19 WARN remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave4:37919] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Disassociated].
19/03/31 22:25:19 INFO actor.LocalActorRef: Message [akka.remote.transport.ActorTransportAdapter$DisassociateUnderlying] from Actor[akka://sparkWorker/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://sparkWorker/system/transports/akkaprotocolmanager.tcp0/akkaProtocol-tcp%3A%2F%2FsparkWorker%4010.0.2.27%3A35254-2#299045174] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
19/03/31 22:25:19 INFO worker.Worker: Asked to launch executor app-20190331222434-0000/4 for JavaWordCount
19/03/31 22:25:19 INFO worker.ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/java" "-cp" "/home/zxd/monotask_jdk1.7/spark-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT-bin-2.6.2/sbin/../conf:/home/zxd/monotask_jdk1.7/spark-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT-bin-2.6.2/lib/spark-assembly-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.6.2.jar:/home/zxd/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.2/etc/hadoop:/home/zxd/monotask_jdk1.7/spark-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT-bin-2.6.2/sbin/../conf:/home/zxd/monotask_jdk1.7/spark-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT-bin-2.6.2/lib/spark-assembly-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.6.2.jar:/home/zxd/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.2/etc/hadoop" "-Dspark.driver.port=42211" "-Xms512M" "-Xmx512M" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "akka.tcp://sparkDriver@master:42211/user/CoarseGrainedScheduler" "--executor-id" "4" "--hostname" "slave4" "--cores" "4" "--app-id" "app-20190331222434-0000" "--worker-url" "akka.tcp://sparkWorker@slave4:55970/user/Worker"
19/03/31 22:25:32 INFO worker.Worker: Executor app-20190331222434-0000/4 finished with state EXITED message Command exited with code 50 exitStatus 50
19/03/31 22:25:32 WARN remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave4:60559] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Disassociated].
19/03/31 22:25:32 INFO actor.LocalActorRef: Message [akka.remote.transport.ActorTransportAdapter$DisassociateUnderlying] from Actor[akka://sparkWorker/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://sparkWorker/system/transports/akkaprotocolmanager.tcp0/akkaProtocol-tcp%3A%2F%2FsparkWorker%4010.0.2.27%3A35260-3#479615849] was not delivered. [2] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
19/03/31 22:25:32 INFO worker.Worker: Asked to launch executor app-20190331222434-0000/7 for JavaWordCount
19/03/31 22:25:32 INFO worker.ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/java" "-cp" "/home/zxd/monotask_jdk1.7/spark-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT-bin-2.6.2/sbin/../conf:/home/zxd/monotask_jdk1.7/spark-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT-bin-2.6.2/lib/spark-assembly-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.6.2.jar:/home/zxd/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.2/etc/hadoop:/home/zxd/monotask_jdk1.7/spark-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT-bin-2.6.2/sbin/../conf:/home/zxd/monotask_jdk1.7/spark-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT-bin-2.6.2/lib/spark-assembly-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.6.2.jar:/home/zxd/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.2/etc/hadoop" "-Dspark.driver.port=42211" "-Xms512M" "-Xmx512M" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "akka.tcp://sparkDriver@master:42211/user/CoarseGrainedScheduler" "--executor-id" "7" "--hostname" "slave4" "--cores" "4" "--app-id" "app-20190331222434-0000" "--worker-url" "akka.tcp://sparkWorker@slave4:55970/user/Worker"
19/03/31 22:25:32 INFO worker.Worker: Asked to kill executor app-20190331222434-0000/7
19/03/31 22:25:32 INFO worker.ExecutorRunner: Runner thread for executor app-20190331222434-0000/7 interrupted
19/03/31 22:25:32 INFO worker.ExecutorRunner: Killing process!
19/03/31 22:25:32 INFO worker.Worker: Executor app-20190331222434-0000/7 finished with state KILLED exitStatus 143
19/03/31 22:25:32 INFO worker.Worker: Cleaning up local directories for application app-20190331222434-0000
```

Are there any errors about hadoop version? Maybe I use the wrong hadoop version or jdk version to build Spark.
  Hope someone can give me some suggestions, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I find some errors in the executor:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Datanode-side support for getVolumeBlockLocations() must also be enabled in the client configuration.
```

I set dfs.datanode.hdfs-blocks-metadata.enabled as true in hadoop-site.xml and restart the hadoop cluster. Finally, it works for me.

The error log of executor is in directory: work

```
cd $SPARK_HOME/work/appxxxx/xx(xx is a number)
```